# How to release only independent Apple Watch app to App Store from combined iOS/Watch Xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, apple-watch

I used the iOS app with Watch app Xcode template and plan to eventually release both an iOS app and Apple Watch app. The Apple Watch app is simpler so I'd like to release just the watch app on the App Store initially.

Is it possible to just release the Watch app portion of an Xcode project to the App Store?

Answer (score 0):

First of all You need to have three target at least, iOS app, WatchOS app, and Watchkit Extension app.

- Select watch app and make sure Build identifier follows the pattern **.watchkitapp** (example: com.ryanwatchapp.app.wathckitapp)
- Select watchkit extension app and make sure Build identifier follows the pattern **.watchkitapp.watchkitextension** (example: com.ryanwatchapp.app.wathckitapp.watchkitextension)

---

Other processes are same like iOS apps; archive,increase the build number and submit.